# IDbContextfactory how to cancel an update?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, blazor-server-side

In my Blazor Server application, there is a radzen datagrid. User can update grid rows. The user may change his/her mind during the update and press cancel button. I want to keep displaying the original values not the modified ones after cancel on the grid.

Here is my cancel code:

```cs
public class OrderDetailRepository : IOrderDetailRepository
{
    private readonly IDbContextFactory<IMSContext> _db;

    public OrderDetailRepository(IDbContextFactory<IMSContext> db)
    {
        _db = db;
    }
...
```

```cs
public void Cancel(OrderDetail orderDetail)
{
    using var ctx = _db.CreateDbContext();

    var orderDetailEntry = ctx.Entry(orderDetail);
    if (orderDetailEntry.State == EntityState.Modified)
    {
        orderDetailEntry.CurrentValues.SetValues(orderDetailEntry.OriginalValues);
        orderDetailEntry.State = EntityState.Unchanged;
    }
}
```

The problem is when I debug, orderDetailEntry state is **detached**. Shouldn't the state be modified? I look forward to your help on this.

Thank you.

## Edit: Wider Scope Added

Here is the radzen grid (I simplified):

```
    <RadzenDataGrid @ref="_grid" AllowFiltering="true" AllowPaging="true" PageSize="20" AllowSorting="true" RowClick="RowClick" ExpandMode="DataGridExpandMode.Single"
            Data="@_orders" TItem="Order" EditMode="DataGridEditMode.Single" RowUpdate="@OnUpdateRow" RowCreate="@OnCreateRow" @bind-Value="@SelectedOrders"
            ShowExpandColumn="false" ShowPagingSummary="true" AllowColumnResize="true">
<Template Context="order">
    <RadzenCard Style="margin-bottom: 20px">
        Customer:
        <b>@order?.Customer?.Name</b>
    </RadzenCard>
    <RadzenTabs>
        <Tabs>
            <RadzenTabsItem Text="Order Details">
               <RadzenDataGrid @ref="_gridDetail" AllowFiltering="@(_detailToInsert == null)" AllowPaging="true" PageSize="15" AllowSorting="@(_detailToInsert == null)" Data="@order.OrderDetails" TItem="OrderDetail" EditMode="DataGridEditMode.Multiple" RowUpdate="@OnUpdateRowDetail" RowCreate="@OnCreateRowDetail" AllowColumnResize="true" AllowColumnPicking="true" ShowPagingSummary="true" ColumnWidth="150px" Density="Density.Compact">
                    <Columns>
<RadzenDataGridColumn TItem="OrderDetail" Property="CustomerOrderNumber" Title="Customer Order" OrderIndex="20">
        <EditTemplate Context="orderDetail">
            <RadzenTextBox @bind-Value="orderDetail.CustomerOrderNumber" Style="width: 100%; display: block" Name="CustomerOrderNumber" />
        </EditTemplate>
    </RadzenDataGridColumn>
    <AuthorizeView Roles="Administrators">
        <RadzenDataGridColumn TItem="OrderDetail" Property="PaymentStatus" Title="Payment Status" OrderIndex="21">
            <EditTemplate Context="orderDetail">
                <RadzenDropDown AllowClear="true" TValue="string" @bind-Value="orderDetail.PaymentStatus" Class="w-100" Data=@paymentStatus Name="PaymentStatus" />
            </EditTemplate>
        </RadzenDataGridColumn>
    </AuthorizeView>
    <RadzenDataGridColumn TItem="OrderDetail" Property="OrderId" Title="Order Id" OrderIndex="22" />
    <RadzenDataGridColumn TItem="OrderDetail" Context="orderDetail" Filterable="false" Sortable="false" TextAlign="TextAlign.Center" Width="200px" OrderIndex="22">
        <Template Context="detail">
            <RadzenButton Icon="edit" ButtonStyle="ButtonStyle.Primary" Class="m-1" Click="@(args => EditRowDetail(detail))" @onclick:stopPropagation="true" Size="ButtonSize.Small">
            </RadzenButton>
        </Template>
        <EditTemplate Context="detail">
            <RadzenButton Icon="check" ButtonStyle="ButtonStyle.Primary" Class="m-1" Click="@(args => SaveRowDetail(detail))" Size="ButtonSize.Small">
            </RadzenButton>
            <RadzenButton Icon="close" ButtonStyle="ButtonStyle.Light" Class="m-1" Click="@(args => CancelEditDetail(detail))" Size="ButtonSize.Small">
            </RadzenButton>
            <RadzenButton Icon="delete" ButtonStyle="ButtonStyle.Danger" Class="m-1" Click="@(args => ShowInlineDialog(detail))" Size="ButtonSize.Small">
            </RadzenButton>
        </EditTemplate>
    </RadzenDataGridColumn>
</Columns>
</RadzenDataGrid>
```

Here is OnInitializedAsync:

```
Enumerable<Order?> _orders = new List<Order?>();
IEnumerable<Vendor?> _vendors;
IEnumerable<Customer?> _customers;


RadzenDataGrid<Order?> _grid;
RadzenDataGrid<OrderDetail> _gridDetail;
    
protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
    user = (await _authenticationStateProvider.GetAuthenticationStateAsync()).User;

    //userName = user.Identity.Name;
    if (!user.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        NavigationManager.NavigateTo("/Identity/Account/Login", false);
    }
    if (DataLoading)
    {
        return;
    }

    try
    {
        DataLoading = true;
        await UpdateOrdersIsCompletedUseCase.ExecuteAsync();
        await UpdateOrdersIsContinuesUseCase.ExecuteAsync();
        _vendors = await ViewAllVendorsUseCase.ExecuteAsync();
        _customers = await ViewAllCustomersUseCase.ExecuteAsync();
        _orders = await ViewAllOrdersUseCase.ExecuteAsync(user);
        
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        throw;
    }

    finally
    {
        DataLoading = false;
    }
    SelectedOrders = new List<Order?> { _orders.FirstOrDefault() };
    SelectedStatus = "";

}
```

Here is making grid editable:

```
async Task EditRowDetail(OrderDetail orderDetail)
{
    await _gridDetail.EditRow(orderDetail);
}
```

Here is the cancel in the grid:

```
private void CancelEditDetail(OrderDetail orderDetail)
{
    if (orderDetail == _detailToInsert)
    {
        _detailToInsert = null;
    }

    _gridDetail.CancelEditRow(orderDetail);
    CancelOrderDetailUseCase.Execute(orderDetail);
}
```

Here is the service:

```
public class CancelOrderDetailUseCase : ICancelOrderDetailUseCase
{
    private readonly IOrderDetailRepository _orderDetailRepository;

    public CancelOrderDetailUseCase(IOrderDetailRepository orderDetailRepository)
    {
        this._orderDetailRepository = orderDetailRepository;
    }

    public void Execute(OrderDetail orderDetail)
    {
        _orderDetailRepository.EditCancel(orderDetail);
    }
}
```

Comment: It should be not attached, EF Core attaches entities when loads them from database and registers them in `ChangeTracker`. Every new `DbContext` has its own `ChangeTracker`, so you are seeing expected behaviour.

Comment: Do you have any guidance on what I want to do? @SvyatoslavDanyliv

Comment: It is UI behaviour, caching old values and remember what is needed to update. EF Core `ChangeTracker` is out of scope here. I think you need more code hat you have expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We would need to see a wider scope of exactly how you are loading your data for the view, then calling this "Cancel" method. However, based on what I see I would recommend *Not* passing entities around outside of the scope of the DbContext that raised them.

What is happening right now is that when you load your view you are loading an entity and sending it to the view to render and update. That entity left the boundary of the DbContext instance that read it, so it is Detached if it was loaded with `AsNoTracking()` or detached from the DbContext, or deserialized. It is effectively a view model, being a copy of data that was once a living breathing EF entity.

Creating a new DbContext instance and calling `context.Entry<detachedEntity>` will just associate the entity with that new DbContext but a detached entity is  always just detached, it's not going to track modifications until after it is re-attached to a DbContext.

Typically for something like a Cancel action you would want to return a model for the view to refresh using rather than passing a reference, or simply purge any state the view is tracking and trigger it to reload with fresh state rather than going through the trouble of reverting changes.

Reverting data changes would involve something like (with the help of Automapper)

```
var existingOrderDetail = ctx.OrderDetails.Single(x => x.OrderDetailId == orderDetail.OrderDetailId);
Mapper.Map(existingOrderDetail, orderDetail);
```

Basically copy the values from the current data state loaded by the DbContext into the detached copy reference. However, this gets considerably more complex if you are dealing with an object graph. (if order detail has a collection of other entities) This would ultimately revert the values in the passed in reference, but that may not necessarily flow through automatically to update a view's display. A better, and simpler solution will almost always be "dump state, reload view".

Update: Ok Blazor server in a nutshell- Blazor can maintain state between updates (requests) by attempting to maintain a circuit for the user's session. At best this is a convenience but cannot be counted on so your application has to be robust enough to handle that scenario.

*If* you were relying on server state, you might try using a single DbContext instance between requests with a tracked OrderDetail that the view might use, but I suspect the OrderDetail entity coming in from the View action may still be a deserialized copy of the tracked entity. In any case it would be unreliable since requests can end up on a different circuit so it's more reliable not to count on that state to be available.

In your case your repository appears to be using a different DbContext for each request. This means the call to

_orders = ViewAllOrdersUseCase.ExecuteAsync(user);

would be loading orders using a new DbContext, so any calls to other Repositories via UseCases passing any one of these entities would be dealing with untracked, detached entities. An untracked entity sent to a view is effectively a copy of data that won't be tracking changes. It's simply the class with it's getters and setters with no EF Proxy around it to do the tracking and provide EntityState or OriginalValues etc. It's a DTO using the entity's `Type`.

Detached entities can be re-attached, but in doing so you have to manually tell EF to expect values to have been modified so EF knows to build an `UPDATE` statement. This is normally the case when trying to update an entity that has been altered. You would Attach it, set it's EntityState to "Modified", then call `SaveChanges`. This isn't a good practice because it treats *all* values as modified (overwriting everything) and is vulnerable to overwrite tampering. (Never trust anything from the client without validating, and only accept what you allow to be changed) It also doesn't apply for your example because what you want to do is revert the changes. EF cannot do that with a re-attached entity because the detached original never had tracking changes details to begin with.

The code I mentioned here:

```
var existingOrderDetail = ctx.OrderDetails.Single(x => x.OrderDetailId == orderDetail.OrderDetailId);
Mapper.Map(existingOrderDetail, orderDetail);
```

*may* work in your case if the object reference (orderDetail) passed into the Cancel action actually results in the client-side view refreshing after the Cancel action is completed. This updates the reference that was passed in, but I don't know if that would automatically, or could manually refresh the UI elements for the view. (It may work, but it may not)  I personally don't do a lot of work with front-end binding like this but typically I would expect a Cancel action for a single line in a grid to simply return the current data state from the DB then the client would replace the content of that data row with the returned data.

```
public orderDetail Cancel(int orderDetailId)
{
    using var ctx = _db.CreateDbContext();

    var orderDetail = ctx.OrderDetails.Single(x => x.OrderDetailId = orderDetailId);
    return orderDetail;
}
```

Where the client-side calling Cancel would receive the current data state OrderDetail and just refresh that row based on a template or manually updating values. (Sorry, I have no love for DataGrids of any type so I cannot really be specific on how that might be done with Blazor bindings)

Comment: I added the simplified wider scope to my question.

Comment: I don't understand this part "What is happening right now is that when you load your view you are loading an entity and sending it to the view to render and update. That entity left the boundary of the DbContext instance that read it" OnInitializedAsync I retrieved the entity and then pass it to the grid to display. Then I do operations on the grid. How can I do this in another way, I honestly don't understand.

Comment: I have updated the answer to hopefully better explain what you are seeing and what you might try. Blazor data binding isn't something I have experience with so perhaps others might chip in some useful tips or design changes to better handle data grid actions with entities.

Comment: A light went on in my head, thank you. Basically, I understood that if I had sent a DTO to the grid to display data and made the transactions on this DTO, and sent DTO to the relevant service methods, I would not have had such problems. Am I right?

Comment: Yes, in that case it would be more clear that you're dealing with just a DTO copy of data. This is the reason I advise devs not to pass entities around outside of the scope of a DbContext since it can be confusing when expecting an entity you could end up receiving a tracked live entity, or an untracked, detached one, or a deserialized block of data cast as an entity.